# Streaming Data Filtering Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am developing a Kafka based streaming data application using Kafka Streams.

Here my application will be processing around 400M of events in peak hours (10 hrs approx), here I need to filter these events based on some multiple filtering conditions and route them accordingly, this conditions can be logical EQUALS, NOTEQUALS, IN, NOTIN

Problem here is I want to write a filter with time complexity of O(1) while looking for some algorithms I came across bloom filter but the problem with bloom filter is it can have false positives and also time complexity is O(H) (here H is no of hash functions).

Another approach I am thinking of creating Hashmap or implementing Caffiene cache where keys will be string value with permutation combinations on filter condition values, here I am worried about the heap memory utilization as permutations will keep on increasing as the HashMap/Cache size

Consider following scenario :

```
empId : 1
deptId : 2
filter_conditions = [
    {field: id, operaor:EQ, value: 1},
    {field: deptId, operaor:IN, value:1,2,3,4}
]
```

can anyone suggest best approach I can take

Comment: I think an optimized algorithm highly depends on the restrictions of your  filtering conditions. Are these only numerical values (in what range?, Integer values?), Strings? (of limited length?, limited character-set?). ...

Comment: filter conditions would only be Strings without any limited length nor limited characters

Comment: I have updated the question with an example

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're looking at data structures like Bloom filters, etc., but first let's talk about your O(1) requirement.

I know you want your filter to be fast, but consider that since you're pulling records from a Kafka stream, you are reading them all from the stream and converting them from bytes into POJOs, and this operation takes at least O(|R|) time for each record, where |R| is the size of the record in bytes.

Your filtering application cannot possibly run faster than this.  Since the lowest possible complexity you can achieve is O(|R|) per record, then you can spend |R| time on each filtering operation and still achieve the lowest possible worst-case complexity.

If your conditions all use the filtering operators that you list: IN, NOT IN, EQUALS, NOT EQUALS, then you are in luck.  You can transform any list of conditions into a filter that you can execute against a record in O(|R|) time.

Your compiled filter should contain the following structures:

- A `Set<String> requiredFields` of fields that MUST be present.  These are all the fields with EQUALS or IN conditions.
- A `Map<String, Condition> conditions` that, for each field mentioned in your filter, contains the condition to apply to that field.
- Each `Condition` needs a `boolean inclusive` and `Set<String> values`. `inclusive == true` means that the value of the field must be in the `values` set.  `inclusive == false` means that the value of the field must not be in the `values` set.

Notice that, no matter how many conditions you have on a particular field, ALL of them can be combined into a single `Condition` object.

Using this representation, we can process each record in time proportional to the record size, without regard to the number or size of the filter conditions.

For each record:

1. Check each field to see if it's in `requiredFields`.  Count the matches, and if it's less than `requiredFields.size()`, then the record doesn't pass the filter.
2. Look up the `Condition` for each field.  If there is one, then check to see if the value is in the `values` set, and then determine whether or not to fail the record based on the value of `inclusive`.

Note that we are iterating only through fields that are actually in the record, and performing a couple O(1) operations on each one.  We are NOT iterating through anything having to do with the number or size of conditions.  This is what allows us to process the record in O(|R|) time.